# Difference between nextAll() and siblings() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

nextAll() in jQuery gets all the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements optionally filtered by a selector whereas siblings() Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
I want to know the difference between both of these

Comment: Check the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/). `nextAll` will return only *following* siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo of what CertainPerformance states.

```js
// Siblings - Gets everyone living in the same container at same level
console.log('Siblings');
$('#mid').siblings().each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log('nextAll');
$('#mid').nextAll().each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p id='mid'>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
</div>
```